# Taking too much time to call promise's then function

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I'm using fetch API to call query the server in my React Native Application. But, My application taking 50 seconds to call `then` function after receiving the response from the server. Am I doing any mistake or Is Promise working very slow?

```
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: bodyContent
    }.then((responseText) =>  {
        console.log(responseText);
        responseText.json().then(function(response){
             console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

`response` is printing in log 50 seconds after the `responseText`

UPDATE : Just now found that the `responseText.json()` promise is executing only after I tap on the screen again. This problem is weird.

Comment: What you looked at the request an figure out where the problem is?

Comment: I was seeing the console log. Its logged responseText first and It logged response after 50 mins.

Comment: So what is taking so long with the request, network panel will show you some details, but you probably need to look at the serverside logs to see what the issue is there. If the issue is in the response callback how big is the reponse that is being returned that it takes forever to parse?

Comment: The console log your refer to is the console.log(responseText) in the code above? Isn't the cuplrit the json function then?

Comment: Server returning the data immediately. responseText is from the server. The json function is taking 50 seconds to extract the `response` from the `responseText`

Comment: @FrederickMotte : json() function looks like the culprit? Is there any other way to get the value?

Comment: What does the response that you return look like? And how large is it?

Comment: Just saying, your function parameters are oddly named :-) `responseText` is actually a `Response` instance, and does not yet have any text - it's still downloading the body. Then calling `json()` waits for the body to end, and parses it into an `object`.

Comment: Problem looks something different. Check the update in the question.

Comment: Thanks all, Finally I found the solution today. It is not because of the fetch API. It is because of the `Chrome debugging` feature in React Native. Check the Answer for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution for this problem. It is because of the `Chrome Debugging`. If I stop chrome debugging, It is working fine. If Chrome debugger is running, I have to tap on the screen for the return value. So, Ignore this delay if you are running chrome debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Since we narrowed it down to the json() call that takes too much time, it seems that this is a reported issue (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6418) that doesn't happen often and so far is not reproducible. It might have to do with structure or size of your json object.

Personally I use the code construct you use quite heavily in my react native apps and there is no performance penalty. However, my typical reponse is quite small and simple (e.g. a list of 10 objects with about 20 keys, no nesting etc.)

You could try the suggestion in the issue report I linked to and use responseText.text() and compare performance.

Answer (score 1):

promise little bit slower than callback. But not 50sec! I think you have problem with internet connection.

Comment: No. If the problem is with internet connection, then It should take more time to print the responseText itself. This promise is just extracting the response from the responseText.

Comment: then problem is responseText.then() maybe data too long exporting from DB or other expression from server. You can measure how long your code runs in backend.

Comment: If you use react native maybe problem with it. maybe that problem with .then(.then())

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, the responseText comes back straight away in milliseconds, but when it convert to json using .json(), it takes a few seconds, the interesting thing is if I click the screen during the .json() parsing period, it get the json data back straight away

Comment: I'm also facing the exactly same problem.

Comment: I found the solution. Check my answer. It is because of Chrome debugging. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm not facing this issues now a days. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to open your webtool kit developper from your browser (commonly F12 key) and go into network tab.

You can see the time that your query take. If it takes long, it's either your network connection or the server which have a delayed response set.

If not, it's client side.

Comment: I'm building react native app. Not normal web application. So, I can't see these things in the network tab.